# Get list of active users in SharePoint Farm

Tags: windows-authentication

I have a requirement where I need to fetch a report to pull all the active users in the SharePoint farm. We are using windows authentication in the farm.

Is there any way through which I can get the count of active users;

Below is query that I'm currently using in DB :

```
Select distinct tp_Title, d. dirname
from WSS_Content.dbo.UserInfo U inner join WSS_Content.dbo.AllDocs D 
             on U.tp_SiteID = D.SiteID 
              where tp_ExternalTokenLastUpdated > DATEADD(d,-1,SYSDATETIME())
```

But i do not want to query the DB instead want to find a way in Sharepoint to achieve this.

Any approach to achieve this will be appreciated.

Comment: define "active user". You mean all active AD accounts? You'll have to query AD for that.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you have configured `audit settings for a site collection`, you can easily get the active users.

- First, [Configure audit settings for a site collection](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-f5a346d0-ee0f-4412-a5e6-d9b5abaa1012)

  [image]
- Second, go to [`audit log reports`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/view-audit-log-reports-4293e8d5-4e7d-4201-b8ac-c8e63a100131#__toc272842194), click on `Content viewing` report to view the **users who have viewed content on a site.**

  [image]

---

**Another custom solution**

- Add JS script code to audit the current login user in Script Editor Web Part in the Home page of your site, check [How to get the login name of the current user using JavaScript?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/73064/how-to-get-the-login-name-of-the-current-user-using-javascript/)
- then add this user to a custom audit list. check [Add new item to list in JavaScript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60005/add-new-item-to-list-in-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

Correction:

```
param($url = $(Read-Host -prompt "Root Site Collection Path"))

#Get the PowerShell Snapin
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"

#Get Root Site
$root = Get-SPSite $url

#If site was found / valid
if($root -ne $null)
{

     foreach($subSite in $root.AllWebs)
      {
       $subSiteTitle = $subSite.Title
        Write-Host $subSiteTitle -ForegroundColor Magenta
        $subSiteURL = $subSite.Url
        Write-Host $subSiteURL -ForegroundColor Cyan

        #get each user
         Write-Host " ------------------------------------- " 
        $siteUsers=$subSite.SiteUsers
        #iterate
        foreach($user in $siteUsers){
            $userLoginName=$user.LoginName 
            Write-Host   $userLoginName -ForegroundColor Yellow

        }


        Write-Host " ------------------------------------- " 
       $subSite.Dispose()
      }

        $root.Dispose()

}
```

Comment: This is for a particular site, i want to get the list of users across farm

Comment: I've corrected the error,I assumed, if you could get it for one site, you should be able to just iterate and get it for all, apologies.

Comment: There are more than 400 application running under the a single farm, Iterating the user per site is not feasible.
i want to know a method where I can find the list of all users in a farm who are active i.e have logged in system for ex say last 30 days

Comment: The only other option I can think of for the scenario you mentioned, is to query the User Profile Service.

Comment: But then there is not flag in user profile through which I can identify the active users.