# Save to draft button in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016, jsom, draft

I have a request to add a *save draft* button in a new form!

how to add this button using javascript and when the user clicks it update list item field *Draft* to yes?

Comment: Do you just need to save item/ file as a draft and handle the draft process? or you have specific requirements to add this button in your form and write code !!?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal to handle the **Draft process**, so I suggest you think first **SharePoint**!

**The SharePoint already handle the `Draft` process as the following:**

***Option 1***

**Draft items in Document library:**

You can handle the draft files by Enabling **Check-Out and Check-in** functionality

- Library setting > Versioning Settings.
- Below `Require Check Out`, check Yes.

[image]

Now `check out` the file, edit and save it as a draft, then reflect your changes by performing `check-In`

> Note: **Check-Out and Check-in** functionality is not available for
>   list

**Draft items in List:**

You can enable the `versioning` with `Content Approval` to handle the draft items by doing the following:

- Open List setting > Versioning Settings.
- Enable `Content Approval`, versioning.
- Set The draft item security as you prefer.

[image]

---

***Option 2***

You can also manage Draft as OOTB as the following:

- Create a `Yes/No` draft field with default value `No`

[image]

- Create a view to filter with Draft = `Yes` and Created By = `[Me]`

[image]

---

***Option 3***

If you have SharePoint Enterprise edition, you can use **InfoPath** to customize your form as the following:

- Add a new  Button, set the display name to `Save To Draft`.
- Add a rule to set the Draft status to Yes.

---

If the above options are not satisfied with your requirements, and you need to do it by adding a button manually, you can check:

- [Add new item to list in JavaScript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60005/add-new-item-to-list-in-javascript)
- [Create A List Item In SharePoint 2013 Using JSOM With Content Editor Webpart (CEWP)](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/create-a-list-item-in-sharepoint-2013-using-jsom-with-content-editor-webpart-cewp)